# How do I count the number of occurrences of a set of characters?

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to compute the number of occurrences of a set of characters in a field, using an awk record.

The set of characters I want to count is the following:

```
!"#$%&'()*+
```

What I've been trying is the following:

```
{
    s = $0;
    print(gsub(/!\"#\$%&\'()\*\+/, "",  s);
}
```

However, if I try to run this script it gives me a syntax error. I think it may be related to the [escaping of special characters in regex in gawk](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk-3.0.3/html_chapter/gawk_5.html), but I am unable to produce a working script.

One simple example is the following:

```
# prints 1
AAAEEEA#AA

# prints 0
AAAEEEAAAA

# prints 4
AA((EE!!AA
```

Comment: Do you want one Count value for any char or a Count for each char?

Comment: You need character classes `[...]`. It doesn't look for each individual character right now.

Comment: Thanks, I need one count for any char. And yes, I'll try with character classes.

Comment: Note: [Don't confuse the POSIX term "**character class**" with what is normally called a regular expression character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). These two are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print $0, gsub(/[!"#$%&\047()*+]/,"&")}' file
AAAEEEA#AA 1
AAAEEEAAAA 0
AA((EE!!AA 4
```

The above lists the characters you're interested in as a **character list** within a **bracket expression** so they are treated as a literal set, uses `\047` to represent `'` so it'll work on the command line or in a file, and uses `&` as the `gsub()` replacement so it doesn't actually change your record without you needing a temp variable.

There may alternatively be a **character class** like `[:punct:]` which can be used inside a **bracket expression** as an alternative to an explicit **character list** that suits your needs, e.g.:

```
$ awk '{print $0, gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"&")}' file
AAAEEEA#AA 1
AAAEEEAAAA 0
AA((EE!!AA 4

$ awk '{print $0, gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"&")}' file
AAAEEEA#AA 1
AAAEEEAAAA 0
AA((EE!!AA 4
```

I highlighted the correct POSIX terminology in bold above. The only other related terminology to be aware of is that you can alternatively specify a **character range** like `a-z` inside a **bracket expression**, e.g. `[a-z]`.

See [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) for more on bracket expressions and character class/lists/ranges.

As for why we use octal instead of hex to represent the single quote in awk, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

---

**Addendum**
There are also other terminologies for Regular Expression matching on sets of characters that are different from the terminology defined by the POSIX standard. So far I've found the following references for each:

POSIX RE Standard:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

Non-POSIX RE Definitions:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

From those and from experience over the past 30 years of using REs and seeing how people refer to the various parts of the REs I've created a table to show the differences in terminology:

```
  Char Set  |       POSIX Terminology       | Non-POSIX Terminology
------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------
    abc     | Character List                | no specific term
------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------
    a-c     | Character Range               | no specific term
------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------
 [:alpha:]  | Character Class               | POSIX Character Class
------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------
   [...]    | Bracket Expression            | Character List or
            |                               | Character Class or
            |                               | Character Set
------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------
   [abc]    | Bracket Expression containing | Character List or
            | a Character List              | Character Class or
            |                               | Character Set
------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------
   [a-c]    | Bracket Expression containing | Character List or
            | a Character Range             | Character Class or
            |                               | Character Set
------------|-------------------------------|---------------------------
[[:alpha:]] | Bracket Expression containing | Character List or
            | a Character Class             | Character Class or
            |                               | Character Set or
            |                               | Bracket Expression
```

In perl `.` alone is also referred to as a Character Class (see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) and several tools and variants of tools (e.g. GNU versions of standard UNIX tools) have shorthand for POSIX character classes such as `\s` for `[:space:]` and have other escape sequences that can be used in the same way as Character Classes - check your tools man page for those.

Best I can tell the POSIX terminology is clear, simple, and unambiguous while the other terminology is ambiguous and confusing so IMHO it's best to just stick to the POSIX terminology.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, as pointed out by [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo)'s comment was to use character list:

```
{
    s = $0;
    print(gsub(/[!"#$%&'()*+]/, "",  s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

single quote needs special treatment, you can do quote chaining as below

```
$ awk '{print gsub(/[!"#$%&'"'"'\(\)*+]/,"")}'
```

also you don't need the provide the third argument, by default it's `$0`.

Comment: Single quote was the thing that gave me headache before, that's why I was using a script file, not one-liner. Nice solution though. Thanks.

Comment: @gc5 The way to get a single quote is with `\047`. Doing so will work whether the script is in a file or on the command line as opposed to the above use of `'"'"'` which will only work on the command line or [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52542833/1745001) of a literal `'` which will only work if the script is in a file.